# Evaluating Nested function call represented as string

Tags: javascript

how to solve nested function call represented as string in javascript
as "PRODUCT(SUM(PRODUCT(2,2),2),3)" => 18
as "SUM(12,PRODUCT(1,2))" => 14

This would be easy using eval().But need to do **without** using eval().

```
const SUM = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
const PRODUCT = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
const evaluateString = str => {
    //code to evaluate "PRODUCT(SUM(PRODUCT(2,2),2),3)"
}
```

Comment: You need to parse the query, build an expression tree and evaluate it.

Comment: However, if you need something like "evaluating code as string", then something wrong in you application architecture (unless you are building code editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yeldar said the cleanest way to do it would be to create syntax tree and to evaluate it but with your given example it looks like you will always get only 2 args since your functions just implement trivials operators. Given those informations it would be a pain to code for such a basic use so i recommand to create your own evaluator in this case.

Ok this is clearly not a very clean way to do and their is probably a lot of possible upgrades but here is a piece of code doing the job :

```js
const SUM = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
const PRODUCT = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
const strToEvaluate = "PRODUCT(SUM(PRODUCT(2,2),PRODUCT(SUM(1,1),2)),3);";

function myEval(str) {
    if(!isNaN(str)) {
        return Number(str);
    }
    if(str.includes('(')) {
        let fn = str.split('(')[0];
        let pos = getParenthesisAndComaPos(str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1));
        let arg1 = myEval(str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1).substring(0, pos[0]));
        let arg2 = myEval(str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1).substring(pos[0]+1, pos[1]));
        switch(fn) {
         case 'PRODUCT':
               return PRODUCT(arg1, arg2);
            case 'SUM':
               return SUM(arg1, arg2);
        }
    }
}

//Will return a tab with position of the coma between arg0 and arg1 and position of the end parenthesis
function getParenthesisAndComaPos(str) {
    let counter = 1;
    let i=0;
    let c=0;
    while (counter>0 && i<=str.length) {
   if(counter==1 && str.charAt(i)==',') {
         c = i;
        }
   if(str.charAt(i)==')') {
         counter--;
        } else if(str.charAt(i)=='(') {
          counter++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return [c, i-1];
}

console.log(myEval(strToEvaluate));
```